# The smallest positive number $x_0$ exists such that $f(x_0)=0$

Tags: general-topology, analysis

Assumption:

$$f\ is\ continuous\ function\ on\ \mathbb{R^1}$$

$$\exists x>0\ \ s.t\ \ f(x)=0$$ 
$$f(0)\neq 0$$
and we know

$$The\ set\ of\ zeros\ of\ a\ continuous\ function\ is\ closed$$

for $x\in(0,\infty]$, prove existence of smallest positive number $x_0$ such that $f(x_0)=0$

Comment: What is E? (need 5 more)

Comment: $E(z)=\sum_{n=0}^\infty\frac{z^n}{n!}$.

Comment: So $C(x) = \frac12(e^{ix}+e^{-ix})=\cos(x)$?

Comment: Yes, however we can't use other properties of cosine function yet.

Comment: I change the problem, more generally.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Let $C=\{ t | t\in [0,x], f(t) = 0 \}$. The set $C$ is compact since $f$
is continuous.

Let $x_0 = \inf C$, then $x_0 \in C$ and since we are given that $0 \notin C$, we see that $x_0 > 0$.